# How do I align checkboxes side by side while I dynamically create them in php?

Tags: php, html, css

I m trying to create a form with multiple checkboxes. The checkboxes are dynamically created from a database but they are always created in a new line while I want them to be aligned side by side. I am new to CSS and php/mysql so I m unable to get it right. Can you help me out?

> 

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'mechuser', 'mypassword', 'mechug_lab');

$query = "SELECT * FROM slots WHERE lab_id = '530_335' AND slot_status = '0' AND expt_id='3'";
$result=mysql_query($query);

if($result) {
                if(mysql_num_rows($result) != 0) {
                    $date = "0000-00-00";
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)):
                    ?>
                    <div><label><?php
                    $date1 = $row['date'];
                    $weekday = date('D', strtotime($date1));
                    $today = date('M j, Y',strtotime($date1));
                    if ($date1 != $date)
                        echo "<strong>".$today."   ".$weekday."</strong> &nbsp";
                        echo " ".$row['slot_time'];
                        $date = $date1;
                    ?>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="bookings[]" value="1"></label></div><?php endwhile;
                    }
                    }
                    ?>
```

Comment: Give the `div` that wraps the checkbox a class and then in your css: `.yourclass { display:inline-block}`

Comment: Just a helpful tip: When dealing with formatting issues like this, I like to mock it up with plain HTML first and get that right, then build the PHP code to echo the HTML according to my working spec.

Answer (score 1):

The div around your checkboxes are block level elements (which makes new lines), you may want to use span (which is an inline level element) instead or make the inline / inline-block elements or float them, the choice is yours :)

`style="display:inline"` or `style="display:inline-block"` or `<span>` instead of `<div>`

Answer (score 1):

Add a class to your div, or target it with specificity if there is a parent.

In your css use:

```
div.yourclass {
   display:inline-block
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/pveez/

Using `display:inline-block` allows you to retain the benefits of wrapping in a `div` (assuming you did this for a reason) while getting the elements to display inline, or "float" next to eachother.

Avoid using inline styles like the other answers are suggesting.

Comment: Inline styling is not always right, but if this is on a huge site (and the checkboxes are only on this page) and the style sheet is already big or this is an template file, it might just be the perfect way.

Comment: Maybe, if this is the _only_ styling you need to apply to the page (something I've never seen before), then I could see inline styling being a decent option.  But why use inline styling if there is already a style sheet? I don't see why it would matter if this is a big or small site, template or not.

Comment: I usually use templates to ease the editing of the site for my customers, if so the probably don't have the skills to find the correct line in the CSS, or even what to write if they were told. If the style is only used on for example the order page, an no-where else. And the site contains several 100pages, your sheet can grow large, and to load all of that styling to the first page may be slowing the site down. I'd prefer another solution  where the sheet can be a little more dynamic for example i often use server-side programming to make "<style>" from the main css based on sections of site

Answer (score 0):

add style="float:left"; to them

```
<div style="float:left;">
```

there are other ways to, like putting them in a table. Or just adding them a `class=""` , and then let the designer format it the way he wants.

Answer (score 0):

A div with `display:inline-block` and set the width to 100/count %. With 4 checkboxes you get them nicely distributed with `width:25%`.